# Getting module addresses with libunwind

Tags: c++, libunwind

I extract the instruction pointer from a stackframe using libunwind like this:

```
unw_get_reg ( &cursor, UNW_REG_IP, &ip );
```

However, this only gives me the dynamic addresses of the function pointers. I would like to receive the static addresses in the modules so I can query them via addr2line.

A different thread didn't receive an answer back then. Do you know how to achieve this info?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that by *static address* you mean offset from the start of the module where the function resides, you may use `dladdr(ip, info)` where `info.dli_fbase` gives you the base address of the loaded module. Then `(pc -  info.dli_fbase)` gives you the offset of this function from the start of the module.